# How can I force Facebook's stream.publish dialog to always open in a new tab or window?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a link with this listener:

```
    $('#share-via-facebook-trigger').click(function () {
      FB.ui(
      {
        method: 'stream.publish',
        attachment: {
          name: "<%= "name" %>",
          caption: 'caption',
          description: "<%= "desc" %>",
          message: "some message ",
          href: "some href "
        },
        action_links: [
        { text: "<%= "text" %>", href: "some url" }
        ]
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
          //alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
          //alert('Post was not published.');
        }
      }
      );
    })
```

If the user isn't logged in to facebook, the link opens in a new window. If the user is logged in to facebook, a dialog opens next to the link right on the page and it get clipped and looks very ugly. How can I make sure the dialog always opens in a new window?

I've tried adding a target="_blank" attribute to the link, but the problem remains. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the same with plain url like [this one](http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response/&link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Dialogs%20provide%20a%20simple,%20consistent%20interface%20for%20applications%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&name=Facebook%20Dialogs). So all you need is just to create a link with `target="_blank"` and such URL.

Comprehensive list of parameters and theirs values you can find in [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)